# Jupyter Notebook Logging ValueError: I/O Operation on Closed File

Tags: python, logging, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to add logging to some Jupyter Notebook code (running Pyspark3).

Digging around SO I found a few answers that said using `basicConfig()` does not work because the notebook starts its own logging session. Some work-around answers pointed to running `reload(logging)` to get around this. With that in mind I am setting up my logging like this:

```
from importlib import reload  # Not needed in Python 2
import logging
reload(logging)
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s",
    level=logging.INFO,
    datefmt="%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Then I run an info statement: `logger.info("this is a test")` and I get an I/O Value error? I am not sure what this means.

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 994, in emit
    stream.write(msg)
  File "/tmp/2950371398694308674", line 534, in write
    super(UnicodeDecodingStringIO, self).write(s)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
Call stack:
  File "/tmp/2950371398694308674", line 700, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/2950371398694308674", line 672, in main
    response = handler(content)
  File "/tmp/2950371398694308674", line 318, in execute_request
    result = node.execute()
  File "/tmp/2950371398694308674", line 229, in execute
    exec(code, global_dict)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Message: 'this is a test'
Arguments: ()
```

This has something to do with logging interacting with stdout/stderr, but I am not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: I got the same error. It is caused by the notebook environment not playing well with the `logging` built-in python module. I'm trying to catch the error and ignoring it, since the logging does happen. Will post code if I succeed.

Comment: Oh, nice! Please do share.

Comment: Worked on this for a while, but did not come up with a fix. Hard to recreate. If I copy the offending code into a fresh notebook, it runs without error.

Comment: Interesting. This might have something to do with my environment then? Im running this on an EMR cluster (version 5.29.0).

Comment: for me, it happens only in jupyter notebooks, and only when I have a lot of code in them. If I paste a minimal version into a fresh notebook, I don't get the error.

Comment: I've been having this same problem, and also can't find a solution. I did however figure out why it is that a minimal version doesn't give the error: because it's run on the same cell. The thing is, when running on pyspark3 kernel, sys.stdout seems to keep changing every time you run a new cell, and with it the stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After my comment above, I've come to make this workaround.

The problem seems to be that `sys.stdout` does not play well with spark, or at least when used by jupyter; you can easily verify this by making a new (Pyspark3) notebook, importing `sys`, and then printing `sys.stdout` in different cells: they will print different objects (in my case, there's 4 of them and it cycles between them, but I can't be sure why is it 4; perhaps it's particular to my cluster config, but it didn't change as I changed number of execs, or cores per exec).

My workaround goes:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.handlers[0].stream.write = print
```

This works because I know my logger has only one handler, and it's `sys.stdout`. If you have more handlers in your logger (say, one stdout and a file), I haven't figured out how to change only the `stdout` one (I can't compare `if stream == sys.stdout` because the whole root of the problem means the object will have changed, unless you do that in the same cell you created the logger), so this workaround may not be for everyone.

If I evolve further, I'll edit the answer with a better solution, but I'm using this for now and it's working like a charm.

Edit: a year later, I'm still doing this the same way

Comment: Hmm, I log to azure app insights with opencensus-ext-azure and when I run you code it says "AttributeError: 'AzureLogHandler' object has no attribute 'stream'". Also, I check sys.stdout in every cell of my notebook and it's always the same yet I still get "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file." Do you any other workarounds for this, by chance?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what app insights or opencensus are. The question and answer are about pyspark jupyter notebooks, is that what you are working on?

Comment: Yes, I'm using them as well. It's just that I am using a custom handler imported from a library to log stuff to Azure. The thing is "logger.handlers[0].stream.write = print" throws me an error and that's why I was wondering if you had some other workaround.

Comment: Oh, got it. Sorry, I don't know this custom handler. But it did get to where I did but messing around with the standard one and finding out; you could try calling "dir(logger.handlers[0])" (or whatever index it is) on your custom one, and see what's inside it!